# Selenium grid2: how to close and open browser on remote

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a test where I need to do a login, close browser and open it again then check something on the page.

How can I do this when running webdriver with remote hub setup? or do i have to run this without remote?

Test is something like this:

1. Open browser
2. Login
3. Close browser
4. Open browser again
5. Check login is remembered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're testing some cookie stuff.  Unfortunately, there's no guarantee any particular node will execute any request, unless you constrain it properly.  You need to have a node advertise a unique capability that the client then requests, ensuring the hub will route to that node every time.  But, naturally, if that node goes down, you won't have any others that could service the request.

Comment: That's a good idea, my problem was exactly that i didn't know which node the next browser would open on. But ofcourse i can just define a custom capability to look for.

Answer (score 2):

The process to accomplish this is going to be very similar to that of a solution in a non-grid environment. Note that the following code is written for Java, but I can't imagine C# being much different.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("hubURL", desiredCapabilities);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("http://path/to/page");
//login to application
driver.quit(); //This will close the browser on the remote machine

//Now to try it again

driver = new RemoteWebDriver("hubURL", desiredCapabilities);
driver.get("http://path/to/page");
Assert.assertTrue(some element that is not on the login page but is on the page after is present);
driver.quit();
```